# how to increase the number of tabs in facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have created some custom apps for facebook page, and also added in as a facebook page tab.

The Question is: I want to increase the tabs on facebook page, right now facebook is giving on 4 tabs 'Timeline', 'About','Photos' or 'Reviews' and 'More'.

I can arrange the tabs and move my custom tabs on the top but I want the more tabs(6 or 7) then there should be 'More...'.

Is it possible in facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Also, the maximum amount of tabs that are visible (including "more") is 12. You can add more as Admin and you will see them all, but only the first 12 will be shown to a User.